# What are the special douchebag gear stats?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I've been looking for the stats for the class specific armor sets since they change with each rank-up but it seems noone has posted them all online.  Considering much about the gameplay is gear based I'd figure someone would have catalogued these by now but apparently not.  I've found lists of every in-game catalogue item, but none of these sets are included.

Though it's easy to find the special weapon stats, feel free to include those as well for completion.

Answer (score 1):

**Halberd of the Warrior**  Automatically obtained when promoted to Sir Douchebag after completing the "Call the Banners" quest.    2 slots 34-47 (x2) level 3

Warrior's Rage: Gain Attack Up after a Perfect Attack.

Armored Strike: Weapon damage increases by 2x your armor value.

**Greatsword of the Warrior**   Automatically obtained when promoted to Commander Douchebag after completing the "Gain New Allies" quest.   2 slots 32-45 (x4)

Warrior's Rage: Gain Attack Up after a Perfect Attack.

Armored Strike: Weapon damage increases by 4x your armor value.

Rend: Destroys 50 armor on Perfect Attack.  level 7

**Greataxe of the Warrior** Automatically obtained when promoted to King Douchebag after completing the "Beat Up Clyde" quest.  1 slot  825-1146 (x2)

Warrior's Rage: Gain Attack Up after a Perfect Attack.

Armored Strike: Weapon damage increases by 5x your armor value.

Rend: Destroys 100 armor on Perfect Attack. level 12

**Wand of Wizarding**   Automatically obtained when promoted to Sir Douchebag after completing the "Call the Banners" quest.    2 slots 16-22 (x3)
+20 Fire

Burning Surge: Gain 2 PP on Perfect Attack on a Burning target. level 3

**Fire Wand**   Automatically obtained when promoted to Commander Douchebag after completing the "Gain New Allies" quest.   1 slot  47-66 (x4)
+50 Fire

Burning Surge: Gain 3 PP on Perfect Attack on a Burning target. level 7

**Wizard's Staff**  Automatically obtained when promoted to King Douchebag after completing the "Beat Up Clyde" quest.  1 slot  431-598 (x3)
+400 Fire

Combustion: On a magic attack, burning damage applies instantly.

Burning Surge: Gain 4 PP on Perfect Attack on a Burning target. level 12

**Push Dagger** Automatically obtained when promoted to Sir Douchebag after completing the "Call the Banners" quest.    1 slot  19-27 (x3)

Piercing: Penetrates 5 enemy armor.

Jagged: Target starts bleeding on Perfect Attack.   level 3

**Throwing Knife**  Automatically obtained when promoted to Commander Douchebag after completing the "Gain New Allies" quest.   1 slot  55 (x4)

Piercing: Penetrates 50 enemy armor.

Jagged: Target starts bleeding on Perfect Attack.

Sharp: Adds 25% damage on Perfect Attack.

Scatter: Hits up to 4 random targets.   7

**Fucking Ninja Stars** Automatically obtained when promoted to King Douchebag after completing the "Beat Up Clyde" quest.  1 slot  333 (x6)

Piercing: Penetrates 25% of enemy armor.

Sharp: Adds 25% damage on Perfect Attack.

Jagged: Target starts bleeding on Perfect Attack.

Scatter: Hits up to 6 random targets.   level 12

**Holy Staff**  Automatically obtained when promoted to Sir Douchebag after completing the "Call the Banners" quest.    2 slots 31-44 (x2)
+10 Holy

Vengeance: Deal 5% more damage when below 25% health.   level 3

**Holy Lance**  Automatically obtained when promoted to Commander Douchebag after completing the "Gain New Allies" quest.   1 slot  121-169 (x2)

Reach: Perfect Attack hits the target plus enemy behind.

Sharp: Adds 20% damage on Perfect Attack.

Strength of Torment: +10% damage per debuff on you. level 7

**Morning Star of David**   Automatically obtained when promoted to King Douchebag after completing the "Beat Up Clyde" quest.  2 slots 721-1002 (x2)
+500 Holy

Reach: Perfect Attack hits the target plus enemy behind.

Vengeance: Deal 10% more damage when below 25% health.

Strength of Torment: +10% damage per debuff on you. level 12

Comment: I know it's been a while and I haven't even played the game recently but I want to state why I've downvoted.  This answer has nothing to do with the armor, which was what I specifically asked about.  All this answer provides is the stats of the weapons, which I already stated in my question are easy to find elsewhere.